# How to transform a non normally distributed data into a normally distributed data using Normal Score Transformation?

Tags: python-3.x, transformation, normal-distribution

I need to transform a non normally distributed data into a normally distributed data using Normal Score Transformation (NST).For that, I'm trying to implement the process which is described in this page " https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/normal-score-transformation.htm ",But yet I could not achieve it in python.
can any one please help me out in this?

Comment: You need to give some more information on your data input, what it looks like, what you have already tried etc. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for reference

Comment: Thanks for reference@nickthefreak